# Magento Currency MX$ Incorrect Format

Tags: magento-1.9, currency

The currency in my Magento isn't 'technically' setup correctly. When converting USD to Mexico Peso's, it writes '1 969,85 MX$' when it should be '1969.85 MX$' (no space and a period, not a comma). Any idea how I would go about changing this?

This is setup in Magento as 'Mexican Peso'. The owner of the site got an email saying that Google has suspended us in South America until we fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone else is struggling. You can access this in /lib/Zend/Locale/Data. This post gives more information: http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-change-currency-symbol-position.html